# Mongodb with django using djongo?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

If I use mongodb in django project with the help of djongo third-party api should I have to use commands migrate and makemigrations again n again when ever I make changes in my models??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to this djongo https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/ 
- You only run the integration once. Once you set it up and working, it forces Django to store everything in MongoDB.
- So when you make changes in your models, the changes are forced into your MongoDB.